# How to use styles depending on two attributes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style

How can I mark symbols in a point vector depending on two attributes?

-> attribute "type" defines the object (triangle, point, etc)
-> attribute "status" defines the color (upcoming, actual, finished, delayed -> green to red)

Comment: Why don't you use Rule-based styling? You can create rules for each attribute combination you have.